# a query string parameter 301 redirect to home

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My Problem is too many backlinks to a utm_source=xxx parameter on domain instead of main domain.
Is it possible to put a rewrite/redirect in my htaccess to redirect `www.mydomain.com/?utm_source=twitterfeed` to `www.mydomain.com` ?
so whenver `www.mydomain.com/?utm_source=twitterfeed` is run it will be redirected to `www.mydomain.com`.

thanks in advance
Ayaz

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to remove the query string, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.mydomain.com? [L]
```

Haven't tested but should work.

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=twitterfeed.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.mydomain.com? [L]
```

Comment: but there are multiple query strings using utm_source . i just want to rewrite the specific, utm_source=twitterfeed . can you modify the code for this please

Comment: great thankx. but as i remmember 301 redirect contains 301 in it. so shouldn't it be [L, 301] ?

Comment: `[R=301, L]` If you want permanent redirection. Default is temp (302).

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you might consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.